# How to document args in Java main

Tags: java, javadoc

How do you go about documenting the contents of the `args` parameter in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

I'm not asking about how to use the `@param` block tag in javadoc, but instead how to document what the contents of each item in the array should be.

For example: "args[1] is width, args[2] is height, etc".

Is `<ol><li></li></ol>` the way to go?

Comment: One consideration is that in the case of `main` (that is, a CLI program), most users won't be reading the source code. There are getopt-style libraries to help you parse command-line arguments, and some of them provide convenience support for printing usage information (such as in the case of invalid input or `--help`).

Comment: Use JCommander to handle this

Comment: Consider that positional arguments (`args[1]` means foo, `args[2]` means bar, etc) are a lot less robust than named arguments (`--foo=...`, `--bar=...` etc), since you can add and remove arguments, but then forget to renumber them in the documentation - or, worse, you've got them baked into scripts which are dotted around your codebase, and you've then got to update them all.

Comment: Regarding the documentation, I'd go for writing a usage message, and in the Javadoc point to that usage message. If the usage message is defined as a constant, you can refer to it directly in the Javadoc (but you might want your usage message to be localized, and then you can only refer to it indirectly).

Comment: Just wondering: I think there won't be much other answers ... thus consider **accepting** the most helpful answer ...

Answer (score 5):

You can only do that in an informal way, by writing down some text within your javadoc that describes the **expected** arguments.

Meaning: there is no single, correct approach here.

In other words: you should use that option, that works best for you, and the other people in your team/project.

If your "team styleguide" allows (asks?) you to use HTML tags within javadoc, then use HTML tags. If your team has some more sophisticated approach that allows for some kind of *markdown* language, then use that. Otherwise, you probably should only be using {@code} to highlight certain parts.

Long story short: **there is no exact rule here; so you should to what best fits your needs**.

But keep in mind: maybe the **javadoc** is **not so important** in the end. If you think your application is used from the command line directly, than your main focus should be that something like "java -jar yourjar --help" gives reasonable output. And that you do not re-invent the wheel in terms of "argument" parsing. In other words: there are quite some libraries out there that you can use for command-line-parsing. And I am pretty sure that they should have support for *documenting* the potential arguments for command line users.

What I am saying is: in a "normal" setup, I would expect that those people interested in invoking your main method will **not** be reading javadoc. They want to look at some help screen to understand which options they can use!

Answer (score 2):

You are at the boundary of the Java framework. Arguments to `main` are provided by the host runtime environment as array of character strings. You will have to write code to define the meaning of these strings. For other methods that you write, you will likely declare multiple arguments to represent each input to that method and make use of `@param` javadoc syntax to document each argument.

See how others do it: [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) - Although this makes use of vararg syntax, it is under the hood converted into an array.

To answer your question: There is no single correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [apache-commons-cli usage](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) documentation which serves as a common library for cli-processing across Java community.

> The Apache Commons CLI library provides an API for parsing command
>   line options passed to programs. It's also able to print help messages
>   detailing the options available for a command line tool.

The last statement resonates with exactly what you are asking. Here are various forms of command-line processing possibilities common-cli supports:

1. POSIX like options (ie. tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz)
2. GNU like long options (ie. du --human-readable --max-depth=1)
3. Java like properties (ie. java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true Foo)
4. Short options with value attached (ie. gcc -O2 foo.c)
5. long options with single hyphen (ie. ant -projecthelp)

If you want to do your own implementation, you can still take a hint from their documentation.